# Rcpp: Shuffling indexes with C++17

Tags: r, rcpp

[Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/stl-random-shuffle/) explains how to shuffle a vector using Rcpp.

However, it uses `std::random_shuffle()`, which is no longer supported in [C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). I naively replaced `std::random_shuffle()` with `std::shuffle()`, but it did not work with C++17.

```
instantiation of function template specialization 'std::shuffle<std::__wrap_iter<int *>, int (&)(int)>' requested here
```

I suppose it's because `std::random_shuffle()` takes `RandomFunc` but `std::shuffle()` in C++17 takes `URBG` ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)).

How can we make this code work with C++17? (How can we define `UniformRandomBitGenerator` using the R randomization feature?)

```
inline int randWrapper(const int n) { return floor(unif_rand()*n); }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector randomShuffle(Rcpp::NumericVector a) {

    // clone a into b to leave a alone
    Rcpp::NumericVector b = Rcpp::clone(a);

    std::random_shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), randWrapper);

    return b;
}
```

My code is more complex than this, but it uses the same trick. It works fine if I link Rcpp with C++11 but not with C++17.

I would like to get the same results from C++17 as well (i.e., I would like to use an R randomizer and make sure the results won't change by changing it from C++11 to C++17).

Now CRAN does not accept C++11 so I need to fix it.

Comment: you should show the code where you replaced `random_shuffle` with `shuffle`

Comment: It's exactly the same code but using `shuffle` instead of `random_shuffle`: `std::shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), randWrapper);`.

Comment: if it was only a rename then there would have been no point in deprecating it. You need to read some documentation to see what you should pass as argument instead https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: If you can't make it work with `std::shuffle` (for some obscure reason), just implement the shuffling algorithm yourself. It's really simple.

Comment: "Now CRAN does not accept C++11 so I need to fix it." is demonstrably false as *many* packages impose it.  R itself now defaults to C++14 (if nothing else is set) but of course still allows C++11 as that is a valid C++ standard.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Now the CRAN check raises a NOTE on this. For example, this package: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-devel-linux-x86_64-debian-gcc/ggraph-00check.html  I suppose CRAN changed (or is changing) its policy but I might get confused.

Comment: That is a) a completely different story you seem to misunderstand (CRAN just suggesting to move from C++11 to C++17 as a package-imposed choice; there is zero information here about CRAN forbidding C++11 as you claimed) and b) I am aware [as I tweeted about just that last night](https://twitter.com/eddelbuettel/status/1619196698693365762) and c) (but you cannot know this) am also in email about this with CRAN maintainers.  In short: you still misread, and hence accidentally spread misinformation.  C++11 remains of course possible and permitted at CRAN.

Comment: I didn't mean to spread the wrong information, but our team got a confusing email that said "CRAN submissions will now auto-reject packages with this NOTE." Does it mean package maintainers cannot update their package if they use C++11?

Comment: Also not correct as stated.  Packages with WARNING and ERROR are auto-rejected. Packages with NOTE go to a manual inspection; many NOTEs are known false positives (spelling in DESCIPTION is a common one) and argued away.  What you and I both noticed is brand-new and currently only in r-devel; sometimes these are also altered.  (In the grand scheme it's all good as CRAN not only allows C++17 but is also moving its baseline from C++14 (currently in R 4.2.*) to C++17.)

Comment: Lastly:  Yoiur bug report on the Rcpp Gallery is valid. It's a pain (and rare) when C++ changes and old code goes away but it sometimes does.  I would love a PR at the Rcpp Gallery for this post if/when you get it worked out.  I am sure there are other example you can lean on.

Comment: OK, my team got confused because the email from the CRAN team said "auto-reject packages with this NOTE." ("auto-reject" sounds like it doesn't go to a manual inspection) It's great to know you already reached out to the CRAN team, thank you.

Comment: This sentence further down is relevant: "If you are fairly certain the rejection is a false positive, please reply-all to this message and explain.".  I get that auto-archive for Rcpp on each upload (see it's CRAN package page and its check results, it's a "grandfathered" exception) so I have to go through this each and every time; same with another package or two among my set.  Auto-admittance is much smoother but hey we can't always have it.  Finally, come to the `r-pkg-devel` list for these questions.  Very friendly with high signal-to-noise.

Comment: Correction:  I was wrong above. CRAN does in fact want C++17 now, and r-devel flags it.  I thought this was still 'in test' but it is indeed live.  I just updated one package of mine accordingly.